# How to predict the error accuracy using these values from weka and how to intepret the output?

Tags: pca, prediction, linear, accuracy, weka

Classifier Model

Linear Regression Model

bug =

```
 -0.1667 * -0.398rfc-0.374wmc-0.347loc-0.328npm-0.264max_cc... +
 -0.0058 * -0.487ic-0.466dit-0.444mfa-0.406cbm-0.29ce... +
  0.0243 * -0.381npm+0.377avg_cc-0.37lcom+0.344amc-0.337wmc... +
  0.0212 * 0.591ca+0.499cbo+0.452noc-0.234avg_cc-0.224max_cc... +
  0.0141 * 0.593lcom3-0.562dam+0.353lcom-0.17moa+0.161cam... +
  0.0697 * -0.519avg_cc-0.481max_cc+0.402amc+0.323ce-0.212noc... +
  0.0911 * -0.684cam+0.32 cbm-0.319dam-0.277lcom-0.223mfa... +
  0.0979 * 0.903moa+0.213cam+0.19 lcom3-0.161ce+0.12 mfa... +
  0.0402 * -0.524noc-0.517amc+0.403ce-0.282loc+0.251cbo... +
 -0.0563 * 0.597noc-0.425ca+0.385ce-0.309amc-0.272cbm... +
 -0.1116 * -0.537loc+0.404lcom+0.342amc-0.268dit+0.233ce... +
  0.0541 * 0.625lcom3+0.614dam+0.257mfa-0.212dit+0.21 cbm... +
  0.3131
```

Time taken to build model: 1.99 seconds

=== Cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.3549
Mean absolute error                      0.4634
Root mean squared error                  1.0668
Relative absolute error                 88.8595 %
Root relative squared error             93.4903 %
Total Number of Instances            87399